# Is there any way to automate windows forms testing?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, automated-tests

I am familiar with nunit for unit testing of the business layer however I am looking now to automate the test of the win forms gui layer.

I have seen [watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) and the watin recorder for automating tests on web application by accessing the controls and automating them. However I am struggling to find a watin equivalent for windows forms (written in c# or vb.net) preferably that is open source.

Does one exist or are all products based on recording mouse and keyboard presses?

**Update:** I have looked at this [blog post on white](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/02/project-white-automated-ui-testing.html) and it seems the sort of thing I am looking for. The blog post raises some issues but as white is only in version 0.6 these may be resolved. Be interested if others have used white or any others for comparison.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out http://www.codeplex.com/white and http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/. We've used the White project with success.

*Same Answer to a previous question*

**Edit**

The White project has moved, and is now located on [GitHub](https://github.com/TestStack/White) as part of TestStack.

Comment: Now deprecated, superseded by FlaUI.

Answer (score 8):

[AutomatedQA's TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/index.asp) is a good testing application to automate GUI testing.  It supports more than just Windows Forms also, so you can reuse it for other applications.  It is not open source and this is the best that I have found.  I haven't seen an open source equivalent to WatiN.  It does have a free trial, for you decide if you like it or not.  The main reason I went with it, is that it really is cost effective, compared to other testing applications.

Answer (score 8):

As a new alternative, I can give you FlaUI (https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI). It is basically a complete re-write of white with more features and a clean code-base.

Answer (score 5):

## The list

Please check the updated list at the: [List of Automated Testing (TDD/BDD/ATDD/SBE) Tools and Frameworks for .NET: User Interface Testing](https://github.com/dariusz-wozniak/List-of-Testing-Tools-and-Frameworks-for-.NET/blob/master/README.md#user-interface-testing)

| Library | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| [Appium](https://appium.io/docs/en/) | Supports testing of Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and Classic Windows (Win32) applications |
| [Coded UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) | *Discontinued* |
| [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI) | Automated UI testing of Windows applications (Win32, WinForms, WPF, Store Apps) |
| [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/) | *Discontinued* |
| [Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/) | GUI testing for desktop, web and mobile applications |
| [Scrutiny](https://github.com/kaeedo/Scrutiny) | F# and C# library for testing state machines by randomly choosing available states and valid transitions. Designed for usage with UI tests. |
| [Squish GUI Tester](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/) | All kinds of cross-platform desktop, mobile, embedded and web applications |
| [TestComplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/overview/) | "Ensure the quality of your application without sacrificing speed or agility with an easy-to-use, GUI test automation tool. Our AI-powered object recognition engine and script or scriptless flexibility is unmatched, letting you test every desktop, web, and mobile application with ease." |
| [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) | *Discontinued* |
| [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) | - Windows Application Driver - Service to support Selenium-like UI Test Automation on Windows Applications - Supports testing Universal Windows Platform (UWP), Windows Forms (WinForms), Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), and Classic Windows (Win32) apps on Windows 10 PCs |

## What Microsoft recommends

### WinAppDriver

Microsoft recommends to use [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver):

> Windows Application Driver (WinAppDriver) is a service to support
> Selenium-like UI Test Automation on Windows Applications. This service
> supports testing Universal Windows Platform (UWP), Windows Forms
> (WinForms), Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), and Classic Windows
> (Win32) apps on Windows 10 PCs.

### Coded UI (Visual Studio ≤ 2019)

Previously, [Coded UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code), a Visual Studio built-in feature and part of the UI Automation, was recommended for application UI testing (**it's deprecated now**):

> Coded UI Test for automated UI-driven functional testing is
> deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where Coded UI Test
> will be available. We recommend using Selenium for testing web apps
> and Appium with WinAppDriver for testing desktop and UWP apps.
> Consider Xamarin.UITest for testing iOS and Android apps using the
> NUnit test framework.

> Automated tests that drive your application through its user interface
> (UI) are known as **coded UI tests (CUITs)**. These tests include
> functional testing of the UI controls. They let you verify that the
> whole application, including its user interface, is functioning
> correctly. Coded UI Tests are particularly useful where there is
> validation or other logic in the user interface, for example in a web
> page. They are also frequently used to automate an existing manual
> test.

Read more at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code

Comment: it's deprecated

Answer (score 3):

[WinAppDriver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver) is a Selenium-like UI test automation service for testing Windows applications including Windows Forms applications. It can be used with [Appium](http://appium.io/), a test automation framework.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [White](http://www.codeplex.com/white) is an abstraction layer over the top of Microsoft's [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348551.aspx) framework. I have written a similar layer that we use internally on our projects and it works great. So White would definattley be worth a look

Microsoft have released the source to UI Automation, so if necessary you should be able to debug right down the whole stack if necessary.

The really cool thing is that with licence cost, you can scale up and run as many machines as you like for execution.

We run inside VSTS and link our results to requirements, but you can use c# express and nUnit and get first class tools and languages for little to no cost.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links from MSDN Magazine on automatic testing code:

- Using UIAutomation [Bugslayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163465.aspx) March 2007
- Using PowerShell [Test Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx) December 2007
- Tester, a utility for recording mouse clicks and keystrokes, then playing them back & program checking behaviour. Excellent for unmanaged code. Uses windows handles so may not work well for managed code.  [Bugslayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc301453.aspx) March 2002.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the Microsoft [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348551.aspx) framework. This has been included in .NET since version 3.0. This is actually what the White framework uses anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Winium(https://github.com/2gis/Winium) that works on multiple Windows platform besides Windows 10 and is similar to Selenium with extra features that support controlling the application remotely.