# How to unit test dialog interaction

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dialog, nunit

I have the following class:

```
public class DirectoryFinder : IDirectoryFinder
{
    public string GetDirectory(string whereTo)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog {Description = whereTo};
        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        return result == DialogResult.OK ? dialog.SelectedPath : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

How would I go about verifying that it returns the correct data?
eg. string.Empty or whatever was selected in the dialog depending on what the user click?

I'm using NUnit as testing framework.

Comment: You can't with pure unit testing since you would need the dialogs result. This more has character of an e2e-test, or ui-test. You will need a testing framework, that simulates a users behaviour. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343/is-there-any-way-to-automate-windows-forms-testing) stackoverflow post helps to find one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to separate out the untestable UI part from the testable business logic:

```
public string GetDirectory(string whereTo)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog { Description = whereTo };
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

    return GetDirectory(dialog.SelectedPath, result);
}

public string GetDirectory(string selectedPath, DialogResult result)
{
    return result == DialogResult.OK ? selectedPath : string.Empty;
}
```

So you would just test the second method, which becomes easy.

---

Another option would be to use mocking/faking of the UI components. However, `FolderBrowserDialog` is **sealed**, which makes this harder.

You could do something like this, **but it's probably overkill**.

First, define an interface for just the parts you want to use:

```
public interface IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper
{
    DialogResult ShowDialog();
    string SelectedPath { get; }
}
```

Then wrap the real `FolderBrowserDialog` in your new interface:

```
public class FolderBrowserDialogWrapper : IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper
{
    private readonly FolderBrowserDialog m_dialog;

    public DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        return m_dialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    public string SelectedPath
    {
        get { return m_dialog.SelectedPath; }
    }

    public FolderBrowserDialogWrapper(FolderBrowserDialog dialog)
    {
        m_dialog = dialog;
    }
}
```

And create a fake version for testing, which just returns the values passed into its constructor:

```
public class FakeFolderBrowserDialogWrapper : IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper
{
    private readonly DialogResult m_result;
    private readonly string m_selectedPath;

    public DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        return m_result;
    }

    public string SelectedPath
    {
        get { return m_selectedPath; }
    }

    public FakeFolderBrowserDialogWrapper(string selectedPath, DialogResult result)
    {
        m_selectedPath = selectedPath;
        m_result = result;
    }
}
```

Then your method can use a `FolderBrowserDialogWrapper` for a real dialog:

```
public string GetDirectory(string whereTo)
{
    var f = new FolderBrowserDialogWrapper(
        new FolderBrowserDialog { Description = whereTo });
    return GetDirectory(f);
}

public string GetDirectory(IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper dialog)
{
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    return result == DialogResult.OK ? dialog.SelectedPath : string.Empty;
}
```

And tests can use a `FakeFolderBrowserDialogWrapper` to bypass the UI:

```
[Test]
public static void TestDirectoryFinderGetDirectoryWithOKExpectThePath()
{
    const string expectedPath = @"C:\temp";

    var dlg = new FakeFolderBrowserDialogWrapper(expectedPath, DialogResult.OK);

    var df = new DirectoryFinder();
    string result = df.GetDirectory(dlg);

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedPath));
}

[Test]
public static void TestDirectoryFinderGetDirectoryWithCancelExpectEmptyString()
{
    const string expectedPath = @"C:\temp";

    var dlg = new FakeFolderBrowserDialogWrapper(expectedPath, DialogResult.Cancel);

    var df = new DirectoryFinder();
    string result = df.GetDirectory(dlg);

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(string.Empty));
}
```

But that's probably over-the-top unless you're creating lots of `FolderBrowserDialog`s elsewhere in your code as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to thank Matthew Strawbrige for his excellent answer. I started out with his answer but I found out that because I was using constructor injection (Caliburn Micro) I customized it to suit myself. First the interface. (I've added a set to the SelectedPath so I can set the starting directory).

```
public interface IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper
{
    string SelectedPath { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    DialogResult ShowDialog();
}
```

Then the implementation

```
public class FolderBrowserDialogWrapper : IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper
{
    private FolderBrowserDialog _dialog;

    public FolderBrowserDialogWrapper()
    {
        _dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    }

    public DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        return _dialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    public string SelectedPath
    {
        get { return _dialog.SelectedPath;  }
        set { _dialog.SelectedPath = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _dialog.Description; }
        set { _dialog.Description = value; }
    }
}
```

The constructor injection which will use the normal FolderBrowseDialog from the class above under normal conditions which you will have specified in your injection framework ;-)

```
public class TestBrowserDialog : Caliburn.Micro.Screen
{
    private IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper _folderBrowserDialogWrapper;

    public TestBrowserDialog(IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper folderBrowserDialogWrapper)
    {
        _folderBrowserDialogWrapper = folderBrowserDialogWrapper;
    }

    ...
    public void Browse()
    {
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And the command executed. I'm using Caliburn Micro which calls the method directly. In other frameworks, it could a delegate command or something else. My Browse method is linked to a button on the View, so clicking the button on the view, activates the Browse command and opens up a BrowseFolderDialog as wanted.

```
    public void Browse()
    {
        _folderBrowserDialogWrapper.Description = "Your description goes here";
        DialogResult result = _folderBrowserDialogWrapper.ShowDialog();
        string path = result == DialogResult.OK ? _folderBrowserDialogWrapper.SelectedPath : string.Empty;

        // Process your result.
        SourceDirectory = path;
    }
```

A fragment of my test code. Here I can test the behaviour of the Browse command was as expected without bringing up the BrowseFolderDialog during the unit test!

```
    [Test]
    public void TestBrowserDialog_Browse_SetsSourceDirectory()
    {
        // Arrange - This is using NSubstitute for Mocking, NUnit for testing
        IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper _folderBrowserDialogWrapper = Substitute.For<IFolderBrowserDialogWrapper>();
        _folderBrowserDialogWrapper.ShowDialog().Returns(DialogResult.OK);
        string testFileDirectory = Path.Combine(NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory, "Directory 1");
        _folderBrowserDialogWrapper.SelectedPath.Returns(testFileDirectory);

        // Insert your own _folderBrowserDialogWrapper for testing purposes
        TestBrowserDialog sut = new TestBrowserDialog(_folderBrowserDialogWrapper);

        // Action
        sut.Browse();

        // Assert - I'm using FluentAssertions
        sut.SourceDirectory.Should().Be(testFileDirectory);
    }
```

I hope this gives someone else ideas on what to do. Matthew Strawbridge's answer has certainly helped me.