# Can i manipulate other applications using Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, automation

I am trying to find a way to interact with a GUI using java, i want to write a script to open an application, enter username and password and click "login" and such things. is there any way to do it?

Comment: Did you try something like [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) ?

Comment: That's a web browser automation, no?

Comment: Yes, but if your application is not a web application you can look for similar softwares/platforms. I think that this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343/is-there-any-way-to-automate-windows-forms-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are searching something like Java robot it is similar as Selenium but for system applications.
I used this to perform UI-Tests in the past http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke

And to launch one System command from java you can use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("System specific command line text here");
```

As well as

```
File file = new File("/absolute/path/to/yourExecutable");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks!